# Xcode: array is empty when used in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've been going over my code now for soon 8 hours, I can't seem to find the error. It worked earlier (I guess I need to be better at using GitHub)...

I'm creating an iOS app in Xcode, it pulls data from Firebase and is supposed to display each entry as a new row in TableView.

It seems to pull the data correctly from database so the DataService code seem to work fine. The problem seem to be with the feedVC.swift controller. Basically 4 rows are shown, but no data is displayed in the cells. And when printing the array it is also empty when printed from the `ViewDidAppear()`. It looks like the array is not ready when the `viewDidAppear()` is ran...

Hope someone can help... sorry for the long code below

Model -> activity.swift

```
import Foundation

class Activity {
private var _userId: String
private var _name: String
private var _type: String
private var _weapon: String
private var _kills: String
private var _sightings: String
private var _note: String


var userId: String {
    return _userId
}

var name: String {
    return _name
}

var type: String {
    return _type
}

var weapon: String {
    return _weapon
}

var kills: String {
    return _kills
}

var sightings: String {
    return _sightings
}

var note: String {
    return _note
}




init(userId: String, name: String, type: String, weapon: String, kills: String, sightings: String, note: String) {
    self._userId = userId
    self._name = name
    self._type  = type
    self._weapon = weapon
    self._kills = kills
    self._sightings = sightings
    self._note = note

}
```

Services -> DataService.swift

```
// this function uses the Model -> activity.swift model and pull all data for each activity in Firebase and append it to an array to be used by the app to generate the table view in FeedVC
func getAllFeedActivities(handler: @escaping (_ activities: [Activity]) -> ()) {
    var activityArray = [Activity]()
    REF_ACTIVITY.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (feedActivitySnapshop) in
        guard let feedActivitySnapshop = feedActivitySnapshop.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

    for activity in feedActivitySnapshop {
        let userId = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "userId").value as! String // pull content from Firebase
        let name = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String // pull content from Firebase
        let type = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "type").value as! String // pull content from Firebase
        let weapon = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "weapon").value as! String // pull content from Firebase
        let kills = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "kills").value as! String // pull content from Firebase
        let sightings = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "sightings").value as! String // pull content from Firebase
        let note = activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "note").value as! String // pull content from Firebase

        let activity = Activity(userId: userId, name: name, type: type, weapon: weapon, kills: kills, sightings: sightings, note: note)
        activityArray.append(activity)
       print("getAll")
       dump(activityArray)
    }

        handler(activityArray)
}
}
```

View -> feedCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class feedCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var profileName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var activityDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sightings: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var kills: UILabel!

func configureCell(profileImage: UIImage, profileName: String, activityDate: String, name: String, distance: String, sightings: String, kills: String) {
    self.profileImage.image = profileImage
    self.profileName.text = profileName
    self.activityDate.text = activityDate
    self.name.text = name
    self.distance.text = distance
    self.sightings.text = sightings
    self.kills.text = kills
}
```

It all should come together here

Controller -> feedVC.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class feedVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var activityArray = [Activity]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        let authVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authVC") as? authVC
        self.present(authVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self



}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DataService.instance.getAllFeedActivities { (returnedActivityArray) in
        self.activityArray = returnedActivityArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    print("test")
    dump(activityArray)
}


// Footer menu

@IBAction func clubBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func recordBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "feedToRecordVC", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func ProfileBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "feedToProfileVC", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func MoreBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
}


}


extension feedVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return activityArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell") as? feedCell else
    {return UITableViewCell() }
    let image = UIImage(named: "profile_image")
    let activity = activityArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(profileImage: image!, profileName: "Test name", activityDate: "8 October", name: activity.name, distance: "8 km", sightings: activity.sightings, kills: activity.kills)
    return cell
}
}
```

Output from Console:

> 2017-10-14 09:56:40.300359+0200 Shoota MapKit[7409:1907989]
>   [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754
>   received sct extension length is less than sct data length test
>   - 0 elements 2017-10-14 09:56:40.619815+0200 Shoota MapKit[7409:1907974] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57 2017-10-14
>   09:56:40.620042+0200 Shoota MapKit[7409:1907974] TIC Read Status
>   [1:0x0]: 1:57 getAll ▿ 1 element   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #0
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "11"
>       - _type: "22"
>       - _weapon: "33"
>       - _kills: "44"
>       - _sightings: "55"
>       - _note: "66" getAll ▿ 2 elements   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #0
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "11"
>       - _type: "22"
>       - _weapon: "33"
>       - _kills: "44"
>       - _sightings: "55"
>       - _note: "66"   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #1
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "AA"
>       - _type: "BB"
>       - _weapon: "CC"
>       - _kills: "DD"
>       - _sightings: "FF"
>       - _note: "GG" getAll ▿ 3 elements   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #0
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "11"
>       - _type: "22"
>       - _weapon: "33"
>       - _kills: "44"
>       - _sightings: "55"
>       - _note: "66"   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #1
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "AA"
>       - _type: "BB"
>       - _weapon: "CC"
>       - _kills: "DD"
>       - _sightings: "FF"
>       - _note: "GG"   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #2
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "Evening hunt"
>       - _type: "Birds"
>       - _weapon: "Browning CAL. 12"
>       - _kills: "3"
>       - _sightings: "20"
>       - _note: "Great day for hunting grouse" getAll ▿ 4 elements   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #0
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "11"
>       - _type: "22"
>       - _weapon: "33"
>       - _kills: "44"
>       - _sightings: "55"
>       - _note: "66"   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #1
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "AA"
>       - _type: "BB"
>       - _weapon: "CC"
>       - _kills: "DD"
>       - _sightings: "FF"
>       - _note: "GG"   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #2
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "Evening hunt"
>       - _type: "Birds"
>       - _weapon: "Browning CAL. 12"
>       - _kills: "3"
>       - _sightings: "20"
>       - _note: "Great day for hunting grouse"   ▿ Shoota_MapKit.Activity #3
>       - _userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
>       - _name: "asdf"
>       - _type: "fdgjj"
>       - _weapon: "gccv"
>       - _kills: "bcc"
>       - _sightings: "Gucci"
>       - _note: "vvbb"

Screenshot of the UI (feedVC.swift)
[image: screenshot of UI]

Comment: can you show the screenshot of UI , you are getting with above code?

Comment: Image of UI now uploaded. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Please don't use (**never** do) private backed variables with leading underscores to get readonly properties. That's ridiculous in Swift. Just delete all private variables and declare the properties as constant for example `let userId: String`.

Comment: Can you ensure that this return statement:  {return UITableViewCell() } doesn't get called (insert a print statement before the return statement and see if it prints anything)?

Comment: I assume you are referring to activity.swift. I guess this is an example of how important it is to have the best teachers :) thanks

Comment: @lukvol: You are on to something. This is getting executed for each cell...

Comment: Dequeing cells is once place where I would use a force downcast rather than a conditional downcast; then you will get a crash if something is wrong with your cell registration and you can investigate the problem.

Comment: @lukvol: I found one error, the table view cell identifier was wrong. However this fixed a part of the problem. Now it displays all the variables that do not come from Firebase, basically the profile_image, dummy test name and date.

Comment: @Paulw11: How would you do that, changes from as? to as! triggers an error in Xcode.

Comment: @Chris_1983_Norway: Do you get the correct values if you print the activity data after this line: let activity = activityArray[indexPath.row] in your cellForRowAt method? It appears that you hardcoded those values when you set your image and call your configureCell method

Comment: @Chris_1983_Norway thats exactly what you want, get the error if you are not dequeueing the cell correctly,helps you identify the problem instantly as suggested by Paulw11

Comment: @lukvol: using dump(activityArray) it prints the full array. And you are right, some of the values are hardcoded, but activity.name, activity.sightings etc should pull variables from the array

Comment: @3stud1ant3: No, I get a build error if I change from as? to as! feedCell. "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'feedCell'"

Comment: @lukvol: both dump(activity) and dump(activityArray) seem to give the right results. Issue seem to be with cell.configureCell(profileImage: image!, profileName: "Test name", activityDate: "8 October", name: activity.name, distance: "8 km", sightings: activity.sightings, kills: activity.kills)

For some reason, it doesn't pull the variables form the array when it configures the cell...

Comment: You don’t use the guard... you just say `let cell=tableview.dequeueResuableCell(withIdentifier:”feedcell”, forIndexPath:indexPath) as! FeedCell` As the force downcast means it is no longer an optional.

Comment: @lukvol: I think I know what the problem is... its the cell height... the variables from the array is "showing", but due to the "not dynamic" cell height I can't see it in the simulator.... Currently it is only showing the hardcoded variables.... the array based variables should be displayed below the hardcoded in the cell...... #%&#$%&

Comment: Yes, the cell height was the error... *feel dumb*

Comment: @Chris_1983_Norway: Also a little hint which might help you in the future: You wrote that *activityArray* would be empty if you print it in the viewDidAppear method. This is the expected behaviour: you set the array in an async callback. This means that the function body of the viewDidAppear method does not wait until the callback is done, it continues with the lines below the *getAllFeedActivities* call. You can verify this by adding a print statement before the line *self.activityArray = returnedActivityArray*. "Test" should be printed before the print statement you've added.